# Facebook authentication in cordova/angularjs app

Tags: facebook, angularjs, cordova

I am trying out the [phonegap-facebook plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) for authentication with facebook, and it works with the examples provided. But now I can't figure out how to configure it properly with angular.

I have tried out Ciul's [angular-facebook](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook) module for this purpose, and it works in the browser, but it is not clear to me how to set it up in a native environment.

The [angular-facebook](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook) module comes with a separate script for phonegap. Anyone here care to explain how the setup should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how i handle it.

I include in my index.html first cordova.js and cdv-plugin-fb-connect and then angular-facebook and angular-facebook-phonegap.js from [Ciul's plugin](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook).

**index.html**:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-facebook/lib/angular-facebook.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-facebook/lib/angular-facebook-phonegap.js"></script>
```

I start by bootstraping Angular.js manually after device ready event. This step may be optional because angular-facebook-phonegap already wait for this event.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

After injecting FacebookProvier in angular config, initiate it.

**angular.config**:

```
var application_conf_mobile = {
    appId: "XXXXXXX",
    oauth: true,
    localSDK: 'facebook-js-sdk.js', //Load sdk async
    nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
    status: false,
    frictionlessRequests: true,
    useCachedDialogs: false,
    cookies:true
}
FacebookProvider.init(application_conf_mobile,false);
```

When debugging, you should double check CDV variable is defined.

You should be able to use the api for instance in a service (inject "Facebook"):

**service**:
call api:

```
Facebook.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  handleStatusChange(response)
})
```

listen events comming from Facebook (the angular facebook plugin trigger them):

```
$rootScope.$on('Facebook:authResponseChange', function(e,data){})
$rootScope.$on('Facebook:login', function(e,data){})
...
```

I hope it will help you and I didn't forget any usefull steps!

Comment: When calling methods on the facebook api, I had to use `FB.getLoginStatus(...)`. Other than that, I think it works now. Thanx!

Comment: angular-facebook module from Ciul provide a provider that is a wrapper arround FB api. You shouldn't have to use directly FB.getLoginStatus. Facebook.getLoginStatus should work if you properly inject "Facebook" provider before using it.

Comment: You are right. It didn't work at first, but now it does. My implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/mlundela/ionic-facebook)

Comment: @MadsLundeland Thank you so much! this worked for android as well. let me know if someone is interested, ill post the code github

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you did! :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MadsLundeland if you could provide the code on github like mentioned that would be great!

Comment: Also, does this use the native Facebook app on the phone primarily and fall back to browser login if Facebook app isn't installed?